# how qglwidget interacts with with other widgets in the main window

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

Basically I would like to show pressed buttons on `Text Edit` widget. The Key event is working for GLWidget. How can I interact with widgets of `MainWindow` from `GLWidget`? This is my code so far,

`mainwindow.cpp`

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{

}
```

`glwidget.h`

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QTimer>
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <QKeyEvent>


class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

    //--------------( Key Event )-----------------//
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event);

private:
    QTimer timer;

};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

`glwidget.cpp`

```
.
.
.    
void GLWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
   qDebug() << event->text() << " is pressed ...";
}

void GLWidget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    qDebug() << event->text() << " is released ...";

     //ui->textEdit->setText("hhh"); <- ????????????????

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just like any other widget.

Put a signal in your `GLWidget` that will be emitted when the key is released

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    ....
signals:
    void textChanged(QString text); 
}

void GLWidget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    qDebug() << event->text() << " is released ...";
    emit textChanged(event->text());
}
```

and connect this signal to your textEdit slot `setText(const QString & text)`.

Comment: in `MainWindow`, I've put `connect(glwidget, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString &text)),
            ui->textEdit, SLOT(setText(const QString & text)) );` but the `glwidget` object is not invisible inside `MainWindow` class